# Windows 10 sleep mode issue (Surface Pro 4)

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, sleep, power-options

I have an issue with my Surface Pro 4 (Windows 10), and it's battery draining while in sleep mode for example yesterday I just let it sleep for the day, after 10 hrs of the surface just sitting there, it was really hot and the battery dropped from 91% to 49% and I noticed that it only happens when the bluetooth radio is ON, it's like the bluetooth adapter won't let windows 10 enter sleep mode.

So I did a sleep study, and I've found this...

[image: Sleep Study]

[image: Event Viewer]

**Sleep study**
As you can see here the Bluetooth adapter is the main offender with over 10 hours of active time, but the only thing I have paired with it is the surface pen and it has less than a minute of active time, and I don't see any other device other than the USB root hub but as far as I understand that's the root where the Bluetooth is connected so it's not a hub I connected to the device.

**Event Viewer**
And here you can see how the USB root is draining power while the system is idle and is skipped over and over again.

---

Currently I was dealing with this issue by manually toggling airplane mode every time I turned the screen off, but sometimes when I forget so the surface can't go to sleep. I pretty much have my surface without any registry modification for the power plans or anything, I just have some software to work with but I haven't messed with the OS like at all.

I was thinking maybe writing a script to automatically disable the Bluetooth adapter once the screen is off or toggle the airplane mode. I actually don't need any of this turned on while I have it on sleep mode so...

Any ideas?, Have you dealt with a similar issue before?, or even better does anyone know how to force windows to stop any offender and not skipping it over and over again?

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: There are settings in *Power Options* for *Wireless Adapter Settings* to minimize power usage on battery, though I don't know if that applies to Bluetooth as well as WiFi, However, you might be better served by going from *Sleep* to *Hibernate* after a fixed time, since *Hibernate* uses *no* power.

Comment: You might look into Suspending or Hibernating your system.  Both are “better” power states than Sleep mode.

Comment: @Ramhound after thinking it a lot I'm really leaning towards hibernating, but I'm still not clear with suspending, is that another state?, because I've only seen shut down, sleep and hibernate maybe I'm missing something? thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Suspending moves all memory onto the disk.  Hibernation is a hybrid power state. Previous commenter indicated Hibernation takes no power which isn’t entirely true: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx#hibernate_state__s4_

Comment: @Ramhound, *Hibernate* uses no power -- see https://superuser.com/questions/561252/hibernate-doesnt-use-power-or-does-it. That said, even when turned off,"completely", Intel AT may continually check the network.

Comment: Microsoft article says otherwise.

Comment: Additionally, the accepted answer states, “Some computers, however, can be configured to (for example) leave the network card powered up when in S4 but turn it off when in S5. In that scenario, power consumption will be higher in S4 than in S5.” which indicates S4 does (or perhaps potentially) use power.

Comment: “which means power consumption of hibernation is very low, almost the same as power off.” Microsoft’s own words on S4 power state.

Comment: As an engineer I read the words “almost the same” which means they are not identical, which means it uses some power.  Having a Surface Pro 3 myself, which uses Hibernation by default, I can confirm it will drain the battery (use the device rarely on trips) routinely have to charge it between uses. All three answers besides the answer (at the time with no votes) indicated that S4 used virtually no power, the 0 vote answer is  to factually correct.